# Pass values from URL in HTML form

Tags: forms, url, parameter-passing

I want to pass two values from a URL to a simple HTML form. What is the easiest way to do that. I've found answers for one value but I'm not very good at JS so I failed to adapt them :(

This is the URL with the valuescom

www.myurl.be?title=titlevalue&startdate=startdatevalue

These are the fields

```
<span>
<label for="title" class="fixed">Title</label>
<input name="title" id="title" size="50"/>
</span> <span></span><br>
<span>
<label for="startdate" class="fixed">Vertrekdatum</label>
<input name="startdate" id="startdate" size="50"/>
</span>
```

Comment: you want to pass params from url to the form, or you want to pass params from form to url?

Comment: @Huan Feng: from URL to form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous scripts had a problem in IE9. This script does the job.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
// get URL variables
var hashParams = window.location.search.toString().substr(1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Url parameters can easily be read using PHP.

```
<?php
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $startdate = $_GET['startdate'];
?>
```

Make sure that your web host supports PHP first. (Most of them do)

Answer (score 0):

As Uncertified Robot said, you can get parameters in URL by PHP.

You can also do this with Javascript :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    console.log(parameters);

    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");

    title = unescape(temp[1]);
    console.log(title);
    temp = parameters[1].split("=");

    startdate = unescape(temp[1]);
    console.log(startdate);
</script>
```

With that, you can have your value in JS variables.

If you want to fill the input value in the form with that. You can try this

```
<script>
var formTitle = document.getElementById("title");
if (formTitle) {
  formTitle.value = title;
}</script>
```

Comment: This works fine in all browsers except in IE (different versions). Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `JavaScript` function to get your QueryStrings; just call the function with parameter name and the parameter value will be returned:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryString(string) {
    var params = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var temp = params[i].split("=");            
        if (string == temp[0]) {
            return temp[1];
        }
    }
}
function go() {
    document.getElementById("title").value= getQueryString("title");
    document.getElementById("startdate").value= getQueryString("startdate");
}
</script>
```

Then, call the `function` `go()` at `body` `onload`:-

```
    <body onload="go()">
    //your content
    </body>
```

Comment: Just call the function with parameter? Did I already said I was bad at JS :)